# Use pdf.js to copy a page from one pdf document into another pdf document

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I would like to be able to use pdf.js to copy one or more pages from an existing pdf document to another pdf document (or a new pdf document).

Ideally I would like to be able specify where in the destination document to include the new page - more than likely this would be at the end of the document.

Once all of the pages have been added to the destination document, the script would then save the modified or created document.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, you can't. PDF.js is a 'parsing and rendering' library. So view only. The FAQs also mention:

> PDF.js is designed for reading PDF files, not editing them.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-annotations

If you want to start editing and manipulating documents. It's likely you'll need a server side component. There are plenty of libraries out there for various different languages.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I found pdfkit.js and blob-stream.js, which allows for the creation of PDF documents.

Comment: Cool, glad you found something that works. Don't forget to add or mark an answer. :)

Comment: It appears that pdf.js does not allow you to create new pages and add an image to the page.

However pdfkit.js does allow you to add an image to a new pdf document, so I think it's possible to use the canvas.todataurl() to grab the contents of a rendered pdf and add it to a new document. 

This isn't ideal, because obviously there may be some loss of fidelity based on what was in the original pdf document (text is now a an image).

I'll post back a snippet of code when I get it all working